# Look for more than one object with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Just started using mongoose. I have a method that essentially looks through my JSON objects. I use the method findOne to do so,

`User.findOne({
      'username': req.body.username
    }, function(err, user) {
      if(user) {
        console.log('that username is taken');
      }
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
    });`

My question is, what if I want to retrieve something like req.body.email and check whether that is stored in the database as well. It works when I create a replica of this method, and just change 'username': req.body.username to 'email': req.body.email, but what if I want to use only one function, can I use something like User.find({ 'email': req.body.email,''username': req.body.username ect. I tried the User.find technique and it did not work. I basically want to check if I have an existing username or email stored in my database and then save the credentials to the database using this

`userDetails.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });`

and do it within one method but I do not know how to merge the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we specify in the find or findone are conditions to find the matching records in our collection. We cannot give conditions, such as username and email as it is.

If we need to give more than one condition then we need to use $and or $or appropriate to our scenario.

$and - 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

$or - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Comment: I have not been aware of a $and or $or, I will definitely look into this.

Comment: I have added the $and and $or references in my answer. Please have a look on it. You can mark it as answered if it solves your problem, and it would be helpful to others who are facing similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use updateMany/ update with multi:true.

```
User.updateMany({
  $or:[
  {
  'username': req.body.username
  },
  {
   'email':res.body.email
  }]
 , userDetail}, function(err, user) {
  if(user) {
    console.log('that username is taken');
  }
  if (err) {
    return done(err);
  }
});
```

If you want to create the whole record, if query not matches, then use upsert:true